# Concept of potential difference

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work, potential, potential-energy

> work done = charge x potential difference

Let's suppose you have two unit charges. They flow across two conductors of identical dimensions. One flows through it in time $t_1$ and the other flows in time $t_2$. Where $t_2 > t_1$. How will you compare the potential differences across the two identical conductors i.e which one is greater and which one is smaller? Please compare the potential differences in terms of work done by the two unit charges while flowing through the conductors in the given amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta V_1 < \Delta V_2$

Work also equals $\Delta K.$ (Actually $q\Delta V = -W$) Assuming they have identical masses and initial velocities, you can use the

following reasoning $$ t_1 < t_2 \implies \Delta K_1 > \Delta K_2  \implies \Delta U_1 < \Delta U_2 \implies  q \space\Delta V_1 < q \space \Delta V_2 \implies \Delta V_1 < \Delta V_2$$

Comment: I didn't understand, how did you get $\Delta U_1>\Delta U_2$??

Comment: $\Delta K = - \Delta U$, this is a consequence of conservation of energy: $0 = \Delta E = \Delta K + \Delta U$. oh wait you're right I forgot to flip the sign. I'll edit

Comment: fixed. Multiplying an inequality by -1 reverses its direction.

Comment: But the minus sign would be multiplied on both the side of the inequality. So, they'll cancel each other out and the equality would remain same. Right?

Comment: No. Think of it this way. -5 < -3 but 5 > 3. I was initially thinking what you were thinking when I typed it up. It can be tempting to think that way if you're not paying attention because you're natural tendency is to notice the symmetry and expect them "to cancel".

Answer (score 0):

You say you have *conductors* "of identical dimensions". You don't specify whether they are made of the same material. If they are, then the fact that $t_1\lt t_2$ would suggest that the accelerating potential (and thus drift velocity) is greater in one case (that's why the charge arrives sooner - it moves faster). Which would mean that more work is done if the time is shorter (larger potential difference, same charge).

Note, however, that when you speak of a conductor, this implies you have a very large number of charge carriers - and that it's impossible to follow one unit charge from one end of the conductor to the other.

That makes this an ill-defined problem to answer properly. You may want to clarify what you need if the above doesn't resolve your confusion.